# Can I use ServiceStack web service with .net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-web-api, servicestack

Can I use ServiceStack web service with .net framework 3.5 **web forms**?

Can I have a small example because I've tried to go through https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Your-first-webservice-explained and stopped at "Let's look at the AppHost's Configure method" line and I didn't know what to do?

As I read it's something like Web API and since ServiceStack is working under 3.5 so I guessed I can use it, or did I got that wrong??

Update: The answer was that I have to create `AppHost` and add it to `Application_Start` :

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public class HelloAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
        public HelloAppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            //register user-defined REST-ful urls
            Routes
              .Add<Hello>("/hello")
              .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");
        }
    }

    //Initialize your application singleton
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new HelloAppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

Reference and FULL example can be found here: http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack supports .NET 3.5. You can checkout the assemblies in NuGet package, they are compiled in .NET 3.5. It has no dependency to Web API, you can create a web service from an empty ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking also to an answer to the question about the url mentioned in the question

Comment: @AMgdy I think you should start from [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice). Basically you need to implement a AppHost first. Configure method is defined there.

Comment: I managed to get it from from another sample: http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.servicestack.net/

Yes it supports 3.5

> ServiceStack binaries only: Minimal installation of ServiceStack containing only the core-binaries (.NET 3.5+)